# No puedo cargar imágenes en un reporte hecho con dompdf en laravel

Tags: php, html

Adjunto parte de mi vista show.blade, la imagen esta en al base de datos la cual se guarda mediante los metodos create y store desde mi controlador pero creo que tengo problemas con la ruta las imagenes se estan guardando dentro de las carpetas  public/imagenes/foto/(aquí están las imágenes de cada alumno)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
  <style>
   table {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
   }

   td{
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 11px;
   padding: 8px;
   } 

   th {
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 11px;
   padding: 8px;
   }

   tr {
    
   }
   
   thead{
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    background:#E5E7E9;

   }
   </style>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

     

 </head>
 <body>
  <h2 align="center"><FONT FACE="times new roman">FICHA DE HISTORIA PERSONAL</FONT></h2>
  <h3 align="center"><FONT FACE="times new roman"><u>{{$formulario->nombre}}</u></FONT></h3>
  <hr style="color: #F2F4F4;" />
  <legend>I. DATOS GENERALES</legend>
  <hr style="color: #F2F4F4;" />

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    
     <table>
    <!--creamos la fila para ingresar el nombre-->
      <tr>
       <th width= "200px" style="background-color:#F2F3F4">Escuela de Formación Profesional:</th>
       <td width= "350px">{{$formulario->e_f_p}}</td>
       <td rowspan="6"><img src="'imagenes/foto/'.$formulario->imagen"></td>
       <!--<img src="'imagenes/foto/'.$formulario->imagen" height="210px" width="160px">-->
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <th style="background-color:#F2F3F4">Nombre:</th>
       <td>{{$formulario->nombre}}</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th style="background-color:#F2F3F4">Sexo:</th>
       <td>{{$formulario->sexo}}</td>
      
       
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th style="background-color:#F2F3F4">Dni:</th>
       <td>{{$formulario->num_dni}}</td>

      </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
        </body>
 </html>
```

también adjunto la función show en mi controlador donde recupero los datos de la bd y las envío a la vista formularios.ficha_historia_personal.show la cual esta dentro de la carpeta resources/views

```
public function show($id)
    {
            $formulario=DB::table('formulario as f')
            ->select('f.idformulario' ,'f.imagen' ,'f.fecha_hora','f.e_f_p','f.nombre','f.sexo','f.num_dni')
            ->where('f.idformulario','=',$id)
            ->first();

             $pdf = \PDF::loadView('formularios.ficha_historia_personal.show', compact('formulario'));

           return $pdf->stream('reporte.pdf');
    }
```

también adjunto la imagen de la capeta de mi proyecto para que tengan una referencia de como colocar mi ruta la vista show.blade esta en la misma carpeta que create.blade solo se llega a ver esa en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago de esta forma, solo te pongo la línea de la imagen.

```
<td rowspan="6"><img src="../public/imagenes/foto/{{ $formulario->imagen }}"></td>
```

Comment: gracias amigo me ayudate un monton}

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, lo que hice fue usar la siguiente función del lado del servidor:

```
public_path('/img/logo.png');
```